# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name Class_Name

Tags: powermock

I am running into the following issue while running the Java test using Maven 3.5.4. and OpenJdk 11.

Below are the versions used:

```
org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.6.5
org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:jar:1.6.5
org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.5
org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.23.1-GA
```

Here is the execution stack trace:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.541 sec <<< FAILURE! - in <Class_Name(hidden)>
    initializationError(<Class_Name(hidden)>)  Time elapsed: 0.018 sec  <<< ERROR!
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name <Class_Name(hidden)>. Reason: null
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:296)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:204)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:89)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:79)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:154)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:47)
        at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:107)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:69)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:36)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
    Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1042)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:996)
        at javassist.CtClassType.instrument(CtClassType.java:1540)
        at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.ClassMockTransformer.transformMockClass(ClassMockTransformer.java:65)
        at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.AbstractMainMockTransformer.transform(AbstractMainMockTransformer.java:62)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:277)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:204)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:89)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:79)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:154)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:47)
        at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:107)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:69)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:36)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Maven Surefire, i.e. 2.22.0?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @Pyves ... Yes we are using 2.22.0 version of surefire

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this issue when upgrading to the latest version of Hibernate (5.3.7.Final). It looks like Hibernate has a dependency on Javassist which was updated to 3.23.1-GA.

There is an issue with the latest version of Javassist and Powermock that should be fixed in Javassist 3.24.0 see: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/924

As a work around until the new Javaassist version is released, adding this to my pom fixed the problem for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.22.0-GA</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response !!! I will check this and update the thread.

Comment: thanks, this solved my issue when I received the same error when trying to mock `JOptionPane`. I was using the same Hibernate version as you and that was the culprit.